# Expressing Kummer U function as Meijer G

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I want to express $U(n,m+n+1,z)$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $m \in \mathbb{N}^+$, $n,m < \infty$ and $z > 0$ in term of Meijer's G-function. Wolfram provides the following equation
$$
U(a,b,z) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(a-b+1)} 
G^{2,1}_{1,2}\left(\left.
\begin{matrix}
1-a\\0,1-b
\end{matrix}\right| z
\right),
$$
You can check it through: http://functions.wolfram.com/07.33.26.0004.01. 
However when I used this equation for my need, it produces
$$
U(n,n+m+1,z)=
\frac{1}{\Gamma(n)\Gamma(-m)} 
G^{2,1}_{1,2}\left(\left.
\begin{matrix}
1-n\\0,-n-m
\end{matrix}\right| z
\right),
$$
which is not valid (the Gamma and Meijer's G terms) according to what I've known.

Answer (score 2):

The last formula is valid as the limit for $m$ approaching an integral value. For your values of the parameters, the function becomes a finite sum:
$$U(n, n + m + 1, z) =
\frac {m! \hspace {1px} z^{-n}} {(n - 1)!} \sum_{k = 0}^m
 \frac {(n + k - 1)!} {(m - k)!} \frac {z^{-k}} {k!}.$$
There are some contrived ways to write a power function as a G-function; they can probably be extended to sums of powers.

Comment: Do you know the reference for your first statement as well as clarify it? And I know about the finite sum expansion (use a simple binomial theorem and the definition of kummer U). Thank you anyway :D

Comment: If $n, m \in \mathbb Z$, then $U(n, n + m + 1, z)$ is defined as $\lim_{\mu \to m} U(n, n + \mu + 1, z)$. The G-function representation $G(n, \mu, z)$ is valid for each $\mu$, provided that $n > 0$. Therefore we can just as well take the limit of $G(n, \mu, z)$.